# Estimate overall joint probabilitiy given pairwise joint probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The true random variables are continuous. But I only have discrete probability distributions as estimation of the continuous random variables.

The following are known.

- $P(X_{i}=x_{i})$
- $P(X_{i}=x_{i}, X_{j}=x_{j})$

Suppose the overall joint probability $P(\vec{X} = \vec{x})$ is a multivariate normal distribution.

How to estimate the overall joint probability as a discrete probability distribution?

Comment: I can get the estimation by expectation maximization. I want to know a more direct way though. Can moment-generating function do this?

Comment: Only the 1st and 2nd moments of single variable normal distribution are nonzero. I guess multivariate normal is the same.

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution):

$\boldsymbol\mu$ is the vector of means.

$\boldsymbol\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix.

$$\begin{align}
f_{\mathbf X}(x_1,\ldots,x_k)
& = \frac{\exp\left(-\frac 1 2 ({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})^\mathrm{T}{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})\right)}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: derivation: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec21-25.pdf